# Slow performence for optimizing gradient in tensorflow

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

I have trouble using tf.Adamoptmizer in tensorflow.

here is the code:

```
dis_diff = base_discriminator(interpolates, self.num_planes, reuse=True,
                                  scope=self.scope, only_gan=True)
gradients = tf.gradients(dis_diff, interpolates)[0]
#this code run for an hour
train_op=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-6).minimize(tf.reduce_mean(gradients))
```

base_discriminator is resnet-50. It would cost about 1 hour for runing the lastest sentences. the code is from wgan-gp.
Do I use it wrong?

Comment: Why are you minimizing mean of gradients? Shouldn't you optimize the cost function, and the optimizer derives its gradient?

Comment: it is a section from wgan-gp. I writed it this way to simplify the question.
Actually the gradients will add to discrimination cost ,and optimize together.I found that when I remove the gradient, it will be fast in optimizer.